# JsonConvert unable to parse

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json string earlier it was working fine. Now its not parsing when I have added the nested items. I want to parse the json array in c#. Here is my json code.

```
{
    "Type": "Hotel",    
    "myArray": [{
        "id": 0,
        "time": ["1", "2"],
        "index": 0,
        "picked": [{
            "id": 1,
            "oc": "1"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "oc": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "time": [],
        "index": 1,
        "picked": []
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "time": [],
        "index": 2,
        "picked": []
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "time": [],
        "index": 3,
        "picked": []
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "time": [],
        "index": 4,
        "picked": []
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "time": [],
        "index": 5,
        "picked": []
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "time": ["3"],
        "index": 6,
        "picked": [{
            "id": 3,
            "oc": "1"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I want like this

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(abovejsonstring)
```

Anybody help me out.

Current Class structure is

```
public class MyObject
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public List<MyArray> myArray { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyArray
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string[] time { get; set; }
        public string index { get; set; }
        public List<Picked> picked { get; set; }
    }
    public class Picked 
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string oc { get; set; }
    }
```

**Error was :**

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.String[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Comment: Can you show us what is the error ?

Comment: try with this:
 public List<string> time { get; set; }

Comment: Bad Luck Arvaan. I tried this.

Comment: Did you try Dictionary<string, object> ?

Comment: Dictionary<string, object> show me the results but tricky with MyArray key values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Tried with

http://json2csharp.com/

http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/

Superb. working.

```
public class WeekArray2
    {

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("time")]
        public string[] time { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("index")]
        public int index { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("picked")]
        public Picked2[] picked { get; set; }
    }


    public class MS
    {

        [JsonProperty("year")]
        public string year { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("month")]
        public string month { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("currentmonth")]
        public string currentmonth { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("community")]
        public string community { get; set; } 

        [JsonProperty("WeekArray")]
        public WeekArray2[] weekarray { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that this is the structure newton sees from the json:

```
public class MyArray
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<object> time { get; set; }
    public int index { get; set; }
    public List<object> picked { get; set; }
}
```

So you should change the array (string[] time) to List time

Edit: Just saw it wasn't the time array, then it's probably because it doesn't recognize the "Picked" object

Comment: Earler it was working fine but I added one more object myArray then it failed.